複数ページのPDFファイルを1ページの縦長のPDFに変換する
複数のページを持つPDFファイルを1ページの長いPDFファイルに変換するツールを作成したいです
どうすればいいでしょうか?
上記のようなことをオンラインで行うツールはありますが、セキュリティ上の懸念からローカルで実行できるようなツールを作りたいと思っています。
PDFを加工できるライブラリとかを使って作るとよいのかなと思うのですが、どのようなライブラリを使うのがいいのでしょうか?

長い1ページに出来るか不明ですが、こんな記事があるので調べてみてはどうでしょう？ 複数のPDFファイルを1つに結合する9つの方法おすすめ！無料ソフトもある

オフラインで使えるツールも存在しますがあくまで自作したいということですね？「PDFを加工できるライブラリとかを使って作るとよいのかなと思うのですが、どのようなライブラリを使うのがいいのでしょうか?」についてはどのような言語を想定していますか？

単純な例なら PDF アプリやブラウザから印刷 > PDFとして出力で、「シート辺りのページ数」を調整すれば連結は可能なようです。

@merino 言語は特に限定しません

@cubick それだと1ページ(例えばA4に設定していたらA4とか)に収まるような小ささになってしまうのです。
タブレット等で見やすいようなどこまでも縦長のPDFにしたいのです

Adobe Acrobat Readerで出来るのでは？ Adobeのお役立ち資料にこんな記事があります。【簡単操作】PDFのページサイズを変更する方法

私の質問「オフラインで使えるツールも存在しますがあくまで自作したいということですね？」についてはいかがでしょうか？オフラインツールであれば"セキュリティ上の懸念"もクリアできるかと思いますが？
